# Magento 1.6 - PayPal Instant Payment Notification Disabled

Tags: paypal-ipn, magento-1.6

I got the following message from paypal saying:

> Please check your server that handles PayPal Instant Payment
>   Notification (IPN) messages. Messages sent to the following URL(s) are
>   not being received: https://www.MYSITE.com/paypal/ipn/ If you do not
>   recognize this URL, you may be using a service provider that is using
>   IPN on your behalf. Please contact your service provider with the
>   above information. Once you or your service provider fix this problem,
>   you or your service provider can resend the failed messages from the
>   IPN History page. If this problem continues, PayPal may disable the
>   IPN feature for your account. Thank you for your prompt attention to
>   this issue. 
>   Thanks, PayPal

My version of Magento is `1.6.0.0` and I am using `Paypal Express checkout`. Furthermore, this url is possibly working (as it doesnot take you to 404, rather gives me a blank page).

Secondly, I looked into the code (app\code\core\mage\Paypal\Model\Express.php) and I see the following line: `->setNotifyUrl(Mage::getUrl('paypal/ipn/'))`

Hence, it looks like a valid url. The only thing left is to add `\index.php\` to it.

So can you please tell me:

1. Is this a valid url for my version of magento and paypal?
2. How to be sure if its working? I did sandbox testing and all was working well. The orders were marked as Processing with paypal info received (including Transaction ID) from paypal... I hope it didnt come from PDT (Payment Data Transfer) instead of IPN.

---

Here is more:
The original email says:

> Once you or your service provider fix this problem, you or your
>   service provider can resend the failed messages from the IPN History
>   page

However, I just checked on paypal.com and there are no failed IPN messages... all messages were sent successfully.

---

[UPDATE]
It works from `paypal>Profile>IPN>IPN History>resent`. But not automatically !! So the URL is working hence proved, but the IPN is not automatically working !

Comment: I'm having similar problem - I'm using Magento 1.7.0.2 with Paypal Standard - I can visit the IPN url in my browser and server log shows a 200 response code. However, the same url when hit by Paypal shows a 404 in the server log.

Comment: hmm. For my problem after investigation and a lot of testing, I found that my site's response is too slow sometimes and hence, few times (3 out of 5), paypal misses it. But I get the rest of the 2 times paypal IPN url working....

Comment: I wounder if we will ever find a solution !! Or I have to manually do the IPN each time from `paypal>Profile>IPN>IPN History>resent` because it works from there!!

Comment: also note: Paypal IPN history pages says IPN response was "200"... so why didnt magento recorded the IPN?!!

Comment: ok this is really helping in solving the issue
https://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/kbase/magento/how-to-enable-error-and-exception-logging-in-magento.html